# Emacs "query-replace-regex" isn't regexing?

Tags: regex, emacs, emacs24

I have a large number of files that need to get a certain function call removed entirely.  The first thing that I did was use `find-dired` to generate a `dired` list of files from `find`'s output:

```
find . \( -type f -exec egrep -q -i -e "awesomeMethod\(\s*true\s*\)" \{\} \; \) -ls
```

Now I have a lot of files.  So I hit `t` to toggle all of them and they become highlighted.  Then I hit `Q`, which brings up `query-replace-regex` for all marked files.  I don't know what the variable is called in each file that I'm getting rid of this call for, e.g., it could be removing `$a->awesomeMethod(true);` or `$betterVariableName->awesomeMethod(true);`, so I need a real regex.  I was thinking `\S+\->awesomeMethod\(\s*?true\s*?\)` or something, and replacing it with nothing.  I know that's definitely not perfect -- it's a context free grammar :-P -- but it will get me close.

I was surprised when this regex didn't match anything, since it's almost the same as the regex that generated my list of files.  Then I saw that even `awesomeMethod\(true\)` didn't match anything, when I was looking right at something it should match.  Thinking that maybe I would have to double-escape the parenthesis because of lisp (even though I'm doing this interactively), I tried `awesomeMethod\\(true\\)` which again didn't match.  Then, surprisingly, `awesomeMethod(true)` *did* match, when that is obviously not supposed to in a regex since `(...)` denotes a capture group.  M-S-% on a single file gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong?  Emacs 24.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis in emacs regular expressions are taken literally unless they're escaped with backslashes (then they denote capture groups).

Here's a link for more information:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html

Comment: Nice, I ended up needing `\S +awesomeMethod(true)`